# How to find the equation of a curve which is not symmetric

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization

[image]

I need to find the equation of f1(x) by these three points (5,4) (2,5 , 0) (0, 1,5). I think it is not a standart symetric parabola.

Comment: Without more details, this problem is not well-defined: what are the requirements on the function? Must it be smooth? A polynomial? Is the point (2.5,0) the global minimum?

Comment: The function should not be a polynomial. It is a curve where the piont (2.5,0) is the minimum. It ij just non symetric parabola. All day I am trying to figure out how to write the equation by these three points. I saw that it should be a biquadratic equation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you right, you could use `Fit`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
data = {{0, 1.5}, {2.5, 0}, {5, 4}};
f = Fit[data, {1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4}, x];
line = 2.5/5 *x + 1.5;
Plot[{line, f}, {x, 0, 5.2}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, 
 PlotLegends -> {line, f},
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[.02], Point[data]}]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I rather to know how exactly to find this equation. What is the way step by step. What is the formula for finding the equation.

Comment: @DimitarKazakov from help on fit, it uses **least squares** method, ,which is standard method. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares  Help gives more information.

Comment: Just pointing out, this solution doesn't make $x = 2.5$ the global minimum, `Minimize[Fit[{{0, 1.5}, {2.5, 0}, {5, 4}}, {1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4}, x], x]` evaluates to `{-0.000612953, {x -> 2.53882}}`.

Answer (score 2):

If we don't care much about what happens when $x < 0$, there's an unique third-order solution based on defined points and derivatives (which the least squares solution, by the way, doesn't fulfill if we assume that $f(\frac{5}{2}) = 0$ is also a local minimum):

```
With[{f = a #^3 + b #^2 + c # + d &},
 (f[x] /. Solve[
     f[0] == 3/2 && f'[0] < 0 &&
      f[5/2] == 0 && f'[5/2] == 0 &&
      f[5] == 4 && f'[5] > 0,
     {a, b, c, d}]) //
   FullSimplify //
  Plot[#, {x, -5, 5}, PlotLegends -> #] &]
```

[image]

Only derivative constraint which is necessary for uniqueness is that of $f'(\frac{5}{2})=0$, but I included the rest nonetheless.

If we make an assumption on the slope of the function for all values (second derivative always non-negative, or "parabola-like"), it must be in this case at least fourth-order polynomial if it's a polynomial at all. We can put these constraints on the solution, but there are infinite number of solutions to this problem, plotting hundred random solutions here:

```
With[{f = a #^4 + b #^3 + c #^2 + d # + e &},
 (f[x] /. FindInstance[
     ForAll[x, f''[x] >= 0] &&
      ForAll[x, f[x] >= 0] &&
      f[0] == 3/2 && f'[0] < 0 &&
      f[5/2] == 0 && f'[5/2] == 0 &&
      f[5] == 4 && f'[5] > 0,
     {a, b, c, d, e}, 100]) //
  Plot[#, {x, -2, 5}] &]
```

[image]

I don't think this problem is very well defined. We can try something more, still.

On basis of visual inspection of the forms of candidate functions, we can try to minimize the value of the function for some value of $x < 0$. In this case all of them yield the same function. This way we can find an unique solution:

```
With[{f = a #^4 + b #^3 + c #^2 + d # + e &},
 (f[x] /. First@Quiet@Solve[
         ForAll[x, f''[x] >= 0] &&
          ForAll[x, f[x] >= 0] &&
          f[0] == 3/2 && f'[0] < 0 &&
          f[5/2] == 0 && f'[5/2] == 0 &&
          f[5] == 4 && f'[5] > 0,
         {a, b, c, d, e}]) //
    (# /. Last@Minimize[# /. x -> -1, a]) & //
   FullSimplify //
  Plot[#, {x, -5, 5}, PlotLegends -> {#}] &]
```

[image]

Comparing the fourth and third order candidate functions over the expected range shows they're almost the same while fulfilling the basic criteria:

```
Plot[
 {-(((5 - 2 x)^2 (-150 + x (60 - 5 Sqrt[334] + (-22 + Sqrt[334]) x)))/2500),
  1/50 (5 - 2 x)^2 (3 + x)},
 {x, -1, 6},
 Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Point[{{0, 3/2}, {5/2, 0}, {5, 4}}]}]
```

[image]

This is also the closest fourth-order solution to the unique third-order solution with constraints used above, measured by minimisation of integration of squared difference of functions over $x\in[0,5]$.

If you are integrating over the shaded area in the original question, the third-order function results a nice rational solution, but the fourth-order solution is close, only about 1.7% off.